# Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Can't determine type for tag '<macro name=\"m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color

Tags: android-studio

Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color">?attr/colorSurface'","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\om\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1ce09498fcaec10fa9a7598817fd5438\material-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

I am getting this error. previously my app is building fine but after i added firebase or created a Default Login activity from android studio getting this error.

PLEASE HELP ME FIX THIS ERROR

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem by changing the versions of following
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'`
`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'`

Seems there is some issue with latest material version

Answer (score 0):

I run the old project which was running properly, but when I ran it after and year I got this error I found out that it was because of the **react-native-screens** package which was written in **package.json** like this "react-native-screens": **"^3.13.1"**, so I fixed it by doing this "react-native-screens": **"3.13.1"**,

~version “Approximately equivalent to version”, will update you to all future patch versions, without incrementing the minor version. ~1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <1.3.0.

^version “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^1.2.3 will use releases from 1.2.3 to <2.0.0.